# Timestamp a cell in Google Sheets if the color of another cell is changed

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a function that works great when someone updates a cell in Google Sheets.

```
   function getDate() {
      return new Date();
    }
```

e.g.
`=getDate(A2)` will timestamp the cell it's entered in every time A2 is updated

However, it doesn't update when I highlight the cell with a color. What else do I need to implement this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use an [installable on change trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to capture events where `changeType` is `EDIT` or `FORMAT` in an `onEditOrFormat(e)` function that checks whether `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveCell()` is in the list of cells that should trigger a timestamp in another cell.

Your `onEditOrFormat()` function must run on a trigger rather than through a spreadsheet formula. You cannot get a permanent timestamp with a spreadsheet formula, even with a custom function, because formula results are refreshed from time to time. When that happens, the custom function gets recalculated and the original timestamp is lost.

The easiest way to insert the current date in a cell is to press **Control + ;** or **⌘;**. See the [keyboard shortcuts](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=spreadsheets_shortcuts&answer=181110) help page.

Many people use simple `onEdit(e)` triggers to create static timestamps. Search this forum for many examples, or take a look at the [timestampMultipleColumns_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/28719648?msgid=28825318) script. Unfortunately, simple triggers cannot capture `FORMAT` events.